# what is difference between RHV and OpenStack

Tags: cloud, redhat, openstack, virtualization, ovirt

Red Hat say RHV(Red Hat Virtualization) is specialized in running traditional apps requiring stability and high performance.

but, as far as I know, these features (instance HA, vertical scaling, ...) are also supported by cloud solutions like OpenStack, Azure and so on.

So, I'm wondering why on earth they say RHV is more recommendable from the view point of stability and performance.

Answer (score 2):

**RHV** is the data-center virtualization solution nearest to VMware vSphere. In the other hand, **OpenStack** is a cloud IaaS capable of compute, network and storage abstraction (mainly). Please do not confuse virtualization platforms with cloud platforms only because RHV and OpenStack both relies on KVM.

If your goal is to have the most tuned and stable virtualization environment and your team is going to manage it (with basic delegations to others), then RHV is what you're looking for. Instead, if you are planning to build a private cloud, with all hardware resources presented at a logical level and managed by other teams/customers, then go with OpenStack.

Please keep in mind that the more abstraction you want to achieve, the more complexity rises (software-defined networks among all others). RHV is simpler hence is consider more stable. Both environments can achieve performance, but dealing with abstraction will make it more challenging.

I suggest you to read [What's the difference between cloud and virtualization?](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/cloud-computing/cloud-vs-virtualization)

Comment: Downvoting, because does not describe technical differences and between both

Comment: I understand your point, @Varun Garg, but making the difference clear between a datacenter Virtualization solution and a private cloud is far more important than comparing features. Most of the causes of cloud shift failure in the past decade were precisely taking OpenStack as an actual hypervisor as many other.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Whether I try to google a lot. From theory, OpenStack has a lot of benefits with dozen of services to support as a public cloud such as DNSaaS, DBaaS, Message aaS v.v... whether ovirt only have VM.

However at basic requirements and basic OpenStack skill level(only able to maintain basic projects keystone, cinder, glance, nova, neutron). It also provisioning VM. Then if I am a customer It's very hard to choose if both are the same function that is provisioning VM.

They often tell the difference is scale. However how big is consider as big? 100 nodes or 1000 nodes. Besides I see summit that OpenStack running on all sizes from small to big.